# How can I deploy `chain link proxy aggregator ` to local chain

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs, chainlink

I am following this doc https://docs.chain.link/docs/consuming-data-feeds/ to setup feeds contract on a local evm (Ganache).It says need to deploy `proxy aggregator contract` and the demo is using `Goerl` testnet. I wonder how I can deploy this aggregator on Ganache for local testing?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t chainlink’s AggregatorV3Interface requires a contract address of specific mainnet or testnet you’re deploying it to. Currently only goreli and ethereum are available so if you wanna test your contract I suggest deploying it to testnet or skipping data feed part and directly putting in the price conversion required without using aggregator.
Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy the [MockV3Aggregator.sol](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-mix/blob/main/contracts/test/MockV3Aggregator.sol) on Ganache and initialize it with decimals and answer.

When you call the latestRoundData() on this mock it will give you the answer with which you initialized the contract